# How to display Real-Time notifications (via Icons) in WordPress

Tags: notifications

I'm trying to use icons to communicate messages between an Admin and the site's Registered Users (both collectively and individually):

1. An Admin to posts a message in some type of back-end interface (Custom Post Type, maybe?)
2. The Admin can designate the individual user(s) or all users (for a site-wide messages)
3. The user(s) see the all the message since the user last logged in via a well recognizable "bell" icon with numbers indicating the number of new messages.
4. [See my example video](https://www.loom.com/share/28a3b97578eb4c8d9c3c7f76cf0bfd67) from a bootstrap template.

I have searched the web, but all i'm getting back is information on Push notifications, which is not what i'm trying to do.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this notification system should update live? for example, if a new notification was added to a user should it update in that instance or only after a refresh? (in SO, when someone comments on you Q, if your page is open you will see it, without any refresh) (this is a big part of starting this answer). When is the notification removed? after a user viewed the quick dropdown or after he clicked on the notification?

Comment: Update live (Ajax?) would be nice, but refresh is acceptable (would love to have an idea of complexity using non-ajax). Notification is removed when user clicks on the notification, but again, as this is new to me, I would defer to any established best practices.